# Clarification on the Zero's of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, residue-calculus

"We can introduce the concept of order of zero at infinity of a function $f(z)$ by considering the order of the zero at $z=0$ of the function $f(1/z)$. calculate the order of all the zero in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ of the functions:"

where $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is the extended complex plane which includes a point at $\infty$.

So, $$\frac{(z+1)^2}{z^3}$$
now i believe this to have a finite zero of order 2 and a pole of order 3. we know that for a meromorphic function that number of zeros in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ = the number of poles and so that suggests we have a single zero at infinity right?

$$f(1/z) = (1/z+1)^2z^3 = \frac{(1+z)^2}{z^2}z^3 = (1+z)^2z$$
and consider z = 0,

If this is correct then moving on,
if we have a rational function say $f(z) = \frac{q_m (z)}{p_m (z)}$ where
$$q_m (z) = \prod_{j \in [1,m]}(z-a_j)$$ and $$p_n(z)= \prod_{j \in [1,n]}(z-b_j)$$

where both $a_j$ and $b_j$ are all distinct.
Considering a contour $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that all the points $(a_j)_{j \in [1,m]}$ and $(b_j)_{j \in [1,n]}$

then we apply the residue theorem to the integral, 
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2 \pi i (N-P)$$
where N is the number of zeros in f, counting multiplicity and P is the number of poles in f, counting multiplicity

Which since they're all distinct would be $(m-n)$ yes? or...we could consider the points at infinity in which case, we'd be looking at the poles and zeros of
$$f(1/z) = \frac{q_m (1/z)}{p_m (1/z)} = \frac{\prod_{j \in [1,m]}(1/z-a_j)}{\prod_{j \in [1,n]}(1/z-b_j)} = \frac{\prod_{j \in [1,m]}(1-za_j)/z^{m}}{\prod_{j \in [1,n]}(1-zb_j)/z^n} = \frac{\prod_{j \in [1,m]}(1-za_j)z^{n}}{\prod_{j \in [1,n]}(1-zb_j)z^m}$$ which as we're only considering $z \rightarrow 0$ in this case we have a single pole (order m) and a single zero (order n) at $z=0$ for $f(1/z): z \rightarrow 0$

in which case $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2 \pi i (P-N)$$

i understand this isnt a proof but this is mostly for my understanding as sometimes the more conceptual questions dont allow for as much physical manipulation...so am i correct in my thinking?

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Your $f$ has multiplicity $n-m$ at $\infty$. For all rational functions, the total multiplicity of the zeros/poles on the Riemann sphere is always zero.

Comment: by that you mean for a rational function, that the number of poles equal the number of zeros right? whether thats at infinity or at not